# How Can You Reformat an OTU Table from qiime2 pathway to Include Sequence IDs?

Tags: sequence-annotation, genomics

I am trying to run Tax4Fun in MicrobiomeAnalyst, but am running into trouble with my table formatting. From the qiime2 pathway, I have an OTU, metadata and taxonomic table formatted like so: [image: feature table]

[image: metadata]

[image: taxonomic table]

In order to use Tax4Fun, I understand that I will need to reformat my OTU table to include sequence IDs so it looks like this example:
[image: sample seq table]

However, I cannot figure out how to merge my sequence files from the qiime2 pathway with the OTU table so it looks like that. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.